# How can I unbind Super+number (1,2,3, ...) from opening apps?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, workspaces, dock, workspace-switcher

I would like to switch my workspaces with the keys <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, etc.

But when I try them after changing the keyboard shortcuts, they open the respective app on my dock.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 8):

To unbind the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd> shortcuts from opening the dock apps you can run:

```bsh
for i in {1..9}; do gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-$i "[]";done
```

Then, to make <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd> switch to the corresponding workspace, run:

```bsh
for i in {1..9}; do gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-$i "['<Super>$i']";done
```

---

To revert to the previous settings run:

```bsh
for i in {1..9}; do gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-$i "[]";done
```

and then:

```bsh
for i in {1..9}; do gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-$i "['<Super>$i']";done
```

Comment: Great answer because I was wondering how to make the opposite of OP!